# contact form group check box array

Tags: php, arrays, validation, checkbox

I have a contact form built with PHP and I had a radio option box (one click) and have changed it to a group check box, which means multiple boxes can be clicked.

However, only the last most click is sent through to my email and playing with the code has messed me up, I am not very clear with the php array code and multiple (({{

Here is the html code

```
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="addon" value="NONE" <?php if (isset($_POST['addon']) && $_POST['addon'] == 'NONE') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> tabindex="4" />  None <br /></label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="addon" value="HKG" <?php if (isset($_POST['addon']) && $_POST['addon'] == 'HKG') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> tabindex="5" />  Hong Kong <br /></label>
    ....
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="addon" value="Other Start City" <?php if (isset($_POST['trip']) && $_POST['addon'] == 'Other Start City') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> tabindex="4" /> Other</label>
```

and here is the php code I have at the moment, but this only gives one answer.

```
    $Indhold .= "Tour Extension: ".$_POST['addon']."\n";
```

I tried changing it to an array (as I followed the tutorial http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-form-checkbox.html) , but then only array was printed on the email.

I also want to include validation on that combi box, if possible.  So they can't choose NONE and HKG, and must click at least one.

Comment: `name="addon"` should be `name="addon[]"`

Answer (score 1):

PHP only populates `$_POST/GET` with arrays if the name ends in `[]` (or `[index]`).

Use `name="addon[]"`

Arrays aren't strings, so you can't just concatenate them. You can use [`implode`](http://php.net/implode/) to convert the members of an array into a single string. You could also use a `for` loop to deal with them one by one.

Comment: So, I tried $Indhold .= "Tour Extension: ".$_POST['addon[]']."\n"; and <label><input type="checkbox" name="addon[]" value="NONE" <?php if (isset($_POST['addon[]']) && $_POST['addon[]'] == 'NONE') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> tabindex="4" />  None <br /></label> but it also doesn't work, just prints 'array'

Comment: @yesmaybe — See the last paragraph of the answer.

Comment: @yesmaybe - You will get `Array` when you will echo `$_POST["addon"]`. You need to use `foreach` to build a string.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to handle the `$_POST['addon']` as an `array` (after naming your checkboxes `"addon[]"`)

```
// make sure at least one checkbox is checked
if (isset($_POST['addon']))
{
    foreach ($_POST['addon'] as $k => $v)
    {
        $Indhold .= "Tour Extension: {$v}\n";
    }
}
```

Or as an alternative:

```
    // make sure at least one checkbox is checked
    if (isset($_POST['addon']))
    {
        $indhold .= 'Tour Extension: ' . implode(', ', $_POST['addon']) . "\n";
    }
```

Comment: So I changed the HTML as follows:
        <label> <input type="checkbox" name="addon[]" value="NONE" <?php if (isset($_POST['addon']) && $_POST['addon'] == 'NONE') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> tabindex="4" />None <br /></label>

But putting the below code in the php code at the top doesn't change anything.  In fact it doesn't show on the email at all, I must be doing something wrong.  Sorry for being a bit thick.

        if (isset($_POST['addon']))
        {
        foreach ($_POST['addon'] as $k => $v)
        {
        $Indhold .= "Tour Extension: {$v}\n";
        }
        }

Answer (score 0):

If in the form there are multiple input elements with a single name(`i.e. not followed by '[]'`) only the latest of all those elements can be retrieved from the submitted form. So if you check more that one checkbox in a single group(`i.e. the checkboxes having a single name which is not in the format 'name[]'` but simple `'name'`) then you can get the last checked checkbox value from the form submit because all the previously checked values in the sigle group get overwritten. Hence you need to use an array for the group name to get all the checked checkbox values in the single group.

So always use the following syntax **in case you have more than one checkbox** in a single group:

```
<input type=checkbox name="check1[]" value="v1">v1
<input type=checkbox name="check1[]" value="v2">v2
<input type=checkbox name="check1[]" value="v3">v3
<input type=checkbox name="check1[]" value="v4">v4
```

But in case of a single checkbox use the following:

```
<input type=checkbox name="check2" value="v1">v1 //No need to append square bracket at the end of the assigned name.
```